# Report rdlc c# wpf

Tags: report, rdlc

I have this problem:

I have a c# wpf application with some rdlc reports. Almost all reports are working good enough.

But there is a problem with one report. It works good, too, but when I click on the small button "Print layout" I get "An error occurred during local reporting processing. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". The report works good in "normal" view, I mean without clicking on "Print layout".
The report is not very complex, has about 5-6 pages and a subreport.

Thanks,
A

Comment: Can you check stack trace and see where and how this error is happened exactly?

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you anyway :-) . I'm not sure how but now it works. I think I had some empty fields (textbox, labels, tables, etc). Now I check everything if empty.

Comment: It's very good that you have commented back on this question even after months.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't enter anymore on stackoverflow since then. I had some problems so I stopped all the software development work.

Answer (score 0):

rebind the data source from report viewer and set dataSourceInstance there...